# How to change the spacing of the patterns in a filled region in PGF/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am trying to change the spacing of dots/lines in patterns in a PGF\tikz image. At the default setting many of the patterns look the same (dots, crosshatch dots, north east lines) are pretty much indistinguishable- see code below!

I presume there is an extra argument one can add to \fill[...] to do the trick, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage[notref,notcite]{showkeys}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
%\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{fullpage}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgflibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{ffqqqq}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{ttzzqq}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]


\fill[line width=0pt,color=ttzzqq,fill=ttzzqq,pattern=crosshatch dots,pattern color=ttzzqq] (5.4,1.2) -- (6.8,1.4) -- (9,-2) -- (8.1,-2.6) -- cycle;
\fill[line width=0pt,color=ffqqqq,fill=ffqqqq,pattern=north east lines,pattern color=ffqqqq] (6.8,2.6) -- (11.2,2.6) -- (11.2,1.4) -- (6.8,1.4) -- cycle;
\fill[line width=0pt,color=qqqqff,fill=qqqqff,pattern= vertical lines,pattern color=qqqqff] (11.2,1.4) -- (9,-2) -- (9.9,-2.6) -- (12.6,1.2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

A recent version of `TikZ` introduces `patterns.meta` library which defines new patterns which can be parametrically adapted. It seems that the new library is still experimental and can be changed. But it does what you want.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, patterns, patterns.meta}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{ffqqqq}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{ttzzqq}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]


\fill[line width=0pt,color=ttzzqq,fill=ttzzqq,pattern=crosshatch dots,pattern color=ttzzqq] (5.4,1.2) -- (6.8,1.4) -- (9,-2) -- (8.1,-2.6) -- cycle;
\fill[line width=0pt,color=ffqqqq,fill=ffqqqq,pattern=north east lines,pattern color=ffqqqq] (6.8,2.6) -- (11.2,2.6) -- (11.2,1.4) -- (6.8,1.4) -- cycle;
\fill[line width=0pt,color=qqqqff,fill=qqqqff,pattern= vertical lines,pattern color=qqqqff] (11.2,1.4) -- (9,-2) -- (9.9,-2.6) -- (12.6,1.2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[pattern={Dots[distance=2mm, radius=1mm]}, pattern color=ttzzqq](5.4,1.2)--(6.8,1.4)-- (9,-2) -- (8.1,-2.6) -- cycle;
\fill[pattern={Lines[angle=45, line width=2pt, distance=2mm]},pattern color=ffqqqq] (6.8,2.6) -- (11.2,2.6) -- (11.2,1.4) -- (6.8,1.4) -- cycle;
\fill[pattern={Lines[angle=90, line width=3pt, distance=10pt]},pattern color=qqqqff, postaction={pattern={Lines[angle=90, xshift=5pt, line width=3pt, distance=10pt]}, pattern color=cqcqcq}] (11.2,1.4) -- (9,-2) -- (9.9,-2.6) -- (12.6,1.2) -- cycle;    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]