# Fill and pattern rectangle with TIkz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill, pattern

I am trying to fill and pattern my rectangles with either dots or dash line dense. But this code generates a rectangle with dash line whose space is somehow large. How can I fill them more dense via Tikz?

```
\filldraw [pattern=north east lines, pattern color=green]
  (15,12)(225,-1080) rectangle (360,-1350);
```

Comment: [Have a look at `patterns.meta` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585000/how-to-change-the-spacing-of-the-patterns-in-a-filled-region-in-pgf-tikz).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the spacing of the patterns in a filled region in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585000/how-to-change-the-spacing-of-the-patterns-in-a-filled-region-in-pgf-tikz)